# Como ocultar a title bar? Crash ao mudar android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou quebrando a cabeça aqui pra ocultar a barra que informa o nome do app...
Já tentei de tudo que vi na internet, nada funciona... E quando eu mudo o `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` para `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` o aplicativo para de funcionar não entendo por qual razão, então o que fiz até agora foi mudar o arquivo java pra ocultar a title bar, mexer no styles.xml pra ocultar a title bar.
Minha API minima é a 15 (Android 4.0.3)

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.knautiluz.feralbytes">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Styles:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Activity:**

```
package com.knautiluz.feralbytes;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Tudo que ocorre no inicio do app > Fica em tela cheia
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

**CRASH:**

> --------- beginning of crash
>
> 06-26 23:13:44.705 2373-2373/com.knautiluz.feralbytes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                                                                               Process: com.knautiluz.feralbytes, PID: 2373
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.knautiluz.feralbytes/com.knautiluz.feralbytes.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a
>   Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
>                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.knautiluz.feralbytes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Gostaria de saber primeiramente o que causa esse crash ao mudar o `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` para `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

Comment: Consegue colocar o log do erro que ocorre?

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni Pronto coloquei! Acho que é esse log...

Comment: Não sei se ajuda, mas estou usando por padrão a Empty Activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça assim.

```
<style name="CustomBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Respondendo a sua pergunda é que você está usando AppCompatActivity e o estilo `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` não é compatível com ela. Bom acho que é isso. Se você ler a mensagem de erro ela diz isso `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme` (você precisa usar um tema Theme.AppCompat).

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Basta fazer isso em Styles.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/SuaCor1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/SuaCor2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/SuaCor3</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Crie um tema baseado no Theme.AppCompat.Light

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

e em seu manifesto coloque

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
```

Referencia:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat)

Espero ter ajudado!